# What's the correct way to create class in JavaScript and pass that to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a complex form with  different tabs, so my ask is to save the entire form data to database on final save. I have the models as per my database as follows, posting sample class

```
public class VesselDetail
{
   public string VesselName { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
   public VesselDetail VesselDetail { get; set; }
}
```

I have created JavaScript models as follows

```
class VesselDetail {
    constructor() {

    }
    VesselName;
}
class MainModel {
   constructor() {
    this.VesselDetail = [];
   }
}
```

On my save I am framing the data as follows

```
 let data = new MainModel();
 let vesselDetail = new VesselDetail();
 vesselDetail.VesselName = "XYZ";
 data.VesselDetail.push(vesselDetail);
 
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/SaveFormData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{mainModel: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        hideSpinner();
    },
    error: function (request) {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

My controller is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostUserData(MainModel mainModel)
{
   return new JsonResult { Data = "OK" };
}
```

Somehow I am unable to see the vessel name that was given. I would like to know are my JavaScript models are correct or should I do any changes? Any better idea to make these models in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it was tested in VS2019 and working properly

```
var mainModel= { VesselDetail : { VesselName :"XYZ"} };
  
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/PostUserData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { mainModel: mainModel),
    success: function (result) {
        hideSpinner();

        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function (request) {
        hideSpinner();
 
    }
});
```

and fix VesselDetail class by adding setter and getter

```
public class VesselDetail
{
   public string VesselName { get; set;}
}
```

And I see a bug in your action. What is a Data?

```
return new JsonResult { Data = "OK" };
```

try this

```
return  new JsonResult(mainModel.VesselDetail.VesselName);
```

but if you like it a hard way you can try this

```
class VesselDetail {
VesselName;
}

class MainModel {
VesselDetail = {};
}

let mainModel= new MainModel();
data.VesselDetail.VesselName="XYZ";
```

UPDATE

Sometimes this working better, depending on net version or if you are using API controller

```
var mainModel= { VesselDetail : { VesselName :"XYZ"} };
  
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/PostUserData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(mainModel),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        hideSpinner();
    
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function (request) {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

but you have to add [FromBody] to action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostUserData([FromBody] MainModel mainModel)
{
   return  new JsonResult(mainModel.VesselDetail.VesselName);
}
```

Comment: I have already get;set; how was your controller code looks like?

Comment: Getting 500 error can I get the controller?

Comment: @Developer What is your controller name?,  you will have to replace "Controller" with it

Comment: Is your controller looks like this `[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostUserData(MainModel mainModel)
{
   return new JsonResult { Data = "OK" };
}`

Comment: I am checking at MainModel to see if VesselName coming

Comment: @Developer my controller action body return  new JsonResult(mainModel.VesselDetail.VesselName);

Comment: Can you share the code in one drive or some where

Comment: 'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Comment: @Developer what net mvc version are you using?

Comment: Setting this works for me `class MainModel {
VesselDetail = {};
}
`

Comment: Why the same code not working when I had it in web api controller?

Comment: @Developer I am sorry , but what code do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237609/discussion-between-developer-and-serge).

Comment: @Developer  I added  an update. Try it . Maybe it what do you need.

Comment: Sure will try and let you know

Comment: I have a class where it accepts List, How to add List of items in javascript?

Comment: @Developer you have to post the example of class and data.

Comment: Here is the fiddle I am trying https://jsfiddle.net/DorababuMeka/6fy3nLak/

Comment: You don' t need any model at client side. Just use this  var crewname=$... var model = { crewName1: crewname1, crewName2: crewname2 }

Comment: I have too many fields that's why I created a model

Comment: I need this to be passed to the controller as we did earlier

Comment: I will have my c# model as follows   `public class BmaModel
    { public List<CrewDetail> CrewDetails { get; set; } }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69380745/create-javascript-class-which-holds-the-list-and-pass-it-to-mvc-controller

Answer (score 2):

Don't hand-construct JSON, it's really easy to get it wrong. In this case, you haven't put the necessary `"` around `mainModel` in the JSON you're sending the server, which makes it invalid. As a result, the server won't be able to parse the JSON it receives.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/SaveFormData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{mainModel: ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}',
//          ^−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− missing quotes
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        hideSpinner();
    },
    error: function (request) {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

Instead, let `JSON.stringify` do it for you:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/SaveFormData',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({mainModel: data}),
//        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        hideSpinner();
    },
    error: function (request) {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
```

Also, unless your server is returning JSON you're not using, you don't need `dataType`. (Even if it is, it should be returning the correct `Content-Type` header in which case `dataType` is redundant anyway.)

I also suggest either consistently using property declaration syntax (which is fairly new) or consistently not using it:

Not using it:

```
class VesselDetail {
}

class MainModel {
    constructor() {
        this.VesselDetail = [];
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
class VesselDetail {
    VesselName;
}

class MainModel {
    VesselDetail = [];
}
```

Here's an example of the JSON that will be produced by your code with the changes above (I've used property declaration syntax — the second set of classes above — but they'll both produce the same thing):

```js
class VesselDetail {
    VesselName;
}

class MainModel {
    VesselDetail = [];
}

let data = new MainModel();
let vesselDetail = new VesselDetail();
vesselDetail.VesselName = "XYZ";
data.VesselDetail.push(vesselDetail);
const json = JSON.stringify({mainModel: data});

console.log(json);
```

As you can see, `VesselName` is not blank.

Comment: Is it mandatory to have constructor? I have so many fields

Comment: I am still getting the VesselName as empty

Comment: @Developer - No, it isn't mandatory. You can do it the way you're doing it in the question as well. I thought it was just the one field. (I've removed that part of the answer.) The code above definitely produces valid JSON containing a non-blank `VesselName`. If you're getting a blank one on the server, either the JavaScript code you're using isn't filling in `VesselName` or the server code isn't looking for it in the right place.

Comment: On the client side I can see but in my MVC controller I couldn't

Answer (score -1):

you put the VesselName out of the builder

should be like this

```
class VesselDetail {
constructor() {
    this.VesselName;
  }
}

class MainModel {
constructor() {
    this.VesselDetail = [];
  }
}
```