# Create JavaScript class which holds the list and pass it to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

This is continuation from here

[What's the correct way to create class in JavaScript and pass that to MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363036/whats-the-correct-way-to-create-class-in-javascript-and-pass-that-to-mvc-contro)

```
public class VesselDetail
{
   public string VesselName { get; set; }
   public string VesselData { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
   public List<VesselDetail> VesselDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I have created JavaScript models as follows

```
class VesselDetail {
    VesselName;
    VesselData; 
}
class VesselDetails {
constructor() {
    this.VesselDetails = [];
}
addVessel(VesselName,VesselData) {
    let p = new VesselDetail();
    p.VesselName= VesselName;
    p.VesselData= VesselData;
    this.VesselDetails.push(p);
    return p;
  }
 }
class MainModel {
   VesselDetails = {};
}
```

In my button click event I will bind the required and passing it to MVC controller as follows

```
let model= new MainModel();
let vesselDetail = new VesselDetails();
vesselDetail.addVessel("vesselName1", "vessel desc");
vesselDetail.addVessel("vesselName2", "vessel desc1");
model.VesselDetails= vesselDetail;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: '{mainModel: ' + JSON.stringify(model) + '}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        
    },
    error: function (request) {
        
    }
});
```

But in the controller VesselDetails is getting as null, what was the correct way to pass list to mvc from JavaScript.

@serge

Here is my c# class as per discussion

```
Public class Attachment {
Public string FileName  {get;set;}
Public string FileType  {get;set;}
}

Public class Report {
Public string ReportName {get;set;}
Public List<Attachment> Attachments {get;set;}
}
```

What can be the equivalent in js and send it to mvc controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have a bug in your javascript classes - double VesselDetails. I offer to use this classes, this is more object oriented style.

```
        class VesselDetail {

        constructor(vesselName, vesselData) {
            this.VesselName = vesselName;
            this.VesselData = vesselData;
        }

        VesselName;
        VesselData;
    }

    class MainModel {

        VesselDetails=[];

        addVesselDetails(...args) {
        this.VesselDetails = args;
        }
   }
```

ajax

```
let model = new MainModel();

//using special function

model.addVesselDetails(
new VesselDetail("vesselName1", "vessel desc")
,new VesselDetail("vesselName2", "vessel desc2")
);

//or directly

    model.VesselDetails.push(
    new VesselDetail("vesselName1", "vessel desc"),
    new VesselDetail("vesselName2", "vessel desc2")
   );

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        
    },
    error: function (request) {
        
    }
});
```

action

```
public JsonResult CreateVessel([FromBody]MainModel mainModel)
{
            // some processing
   return  new JsonResult ( mainModel.VesselDetails[0].VesselName );
}
```

UPDATE

Report class looks for me very alike MainModel class

```
    class Attachment {

        constructor(fileName, fileType) {
            this.FileName = fileName;
            this.FileType = fileType;
        }

        FileName;
        FileType;
    }

    class Report {

        Attachments = [];

        addAttachments(...args) {
            this.Attachments = args;
        }
    }
```

and you can create instances the same way as it is using MainModel

Comment: Hi Serge let's say if I have normal classes as per earlier post will the JSON.stringify works?

Comment: As per here, I can have different classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363036/whats-the-correct-way-to-create-class-in-javascript-and-pass-that-to-mvc-contro

Comment: @Developer , yes certailnly. But you have double VesselDetails.

Comment: @Developer Yes, I offered you the same algoritim in UPDATE section and asked you to test it. It is working properly at my computer. And you still can use another one without stringify it you like it more.

Comment: I mean to say instead of array `class MainModel {
        VesselDetails = []; SomeClass={}
    }`

Comment: @Developer  Why not? It doesnt matter what is data like. Just front end should fit a back end class.

Comment: OK how about this kind of in second class  I had an option to add attachments so how the class should be

Comment: class secondClass { SomeVariable; Attachments;} Attachment is another class in that scenario how the class should like

Comment: @Developer it is hard to understand code from comments. Just add update to this question, I will update my answer, or create another post. It's up to you

Comment: @Developer I updated my answer

Comment: Check my update in question

Comment: @Developer Check my update too

Comment: OK will try it out after some time and will update

Comment: Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431199/encoding-arraybuffer-to-base64-and-passing-it-to-mvc-controller-doesnt-work-for

Comment: Hi I have a similar issue can you look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69491095/how-to-pass-httppostedfilebase-from-javascript-as-model-instead-of-formdata