# How to pass HttpPostedFileBase from JavaScript as model instead of FormData

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to pass the form data with out using FormData by using the JavaScript Model. As my form has many controls I would like to go with Model approach instead of FormData.

Is there a way to pass selected files to controller with out using HttpPostedFileBase? I have nearly 10 different class which accepts HttpPostedFileBase

I have a class as follows in c#

```
public class ArtGallery{
   Public string GallerName {get;set;}
   Public HttpPostedFileBase[] Documents {get;set;}
}
```

The equivalent JavaScript Model is

```
class ArtGallery{
     GallerName;
     Documents[];
}
```

On my save of the form here is how I am doing it

```
function saveFormData(){
  let gallery = new ArtGallery();
  gallery.GallerName = "Test";
  $.each($("input[type=file]"), function (i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files, function (j, file) {
            gallery.Documents.push(file);
        });
   });
   saveToDb();
}

function saveToDb() {
    let url = "/MyController/PostData/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: '{gallery : ' + JSON.stringify(gallery) + '}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (request) {
        }
    });
}
```

My controller is as follows, which is getting triggered but documents I am unable to get

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PostUserData(ArtGallery gallery) {

}
```

Comment: How is your Document Model looks like? what you see when you write `JSON.stringify(console.gallery.Documents)`

Comment: @Developer It is showing empty :(

Comment: then there is some issue with stringify of documents